# .Net Template Engine/Report Solution

Tags: .net, open-source, reporting

I am looking to add custom reports/forms to a web application.  I want users to be able to upload a report definition/template file and then be able to print out a PDF or word document (one or the other it doesn't need to be both) for each of their widgets based off of the template they uploaded.   I can't install anything on the server and am looking for an open source/free solution.

Data Source- The data will be in the form of a datatable or dataset that the application fetches itself.  The report tool does will not be able to connect to any database.

Comment: Where will  the data for the reports come from, and what reporting facilities do you need? By that I mean grouping, report headers+footers, page headers+footers, etc.

Comment: I will not need any header/footer capabilities.  Grouping would be nice but is not required.

Answer (score 0):

We're pretty happy with the free [StringTemplate.Net](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) library for generating HTML reports (or any other text-based format). The templating language is simple enough that anyone who understands HTML should be able to adapt the templates. The HTML reports can be shown directly in the application with the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), and we use a [commercial library](http://www.html-to-pdf.net) to convert the HTML to PDF if desired.

A StringTemplate example from the [5 minute introduction](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction):

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title>$title$</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p>Hello again, $name$ !</p>
       <p>Greetings to your friends $friends; separator=", "$</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

We have also used [Microsoft ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) before. This does have the advantage of coming with a viewer control for both WinForms and WebForms, export to pdf and excel, a search feature, SQL Server integration and advanced printing options. But  AFAIK it requires Visual Studio to create/customize reports with the
Report Designer; it does not really support report customization by end users. It seems to be more oriented towards the drag-and-drop programmer working in an environment with a full microsoft stack (IIS, ASP.NET, SQL Server).

Comment: I did look at the ReportViewer but I found it lacking as I couldn't really make a form with it.  If I just wanted to pass it a DataTable with a single record and then use that record to fill out a form it didn't quiet work as I am used to using Crystal Reports where you can embed a field/parameter into a block of text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a .net library intended to do this job. It works with RTF files. You provide the template and the data and it generates the RTF report.
It includes a propietary programming language (a very little but powerful one :) ) including Loops for datatables (with and without conditions) and an "IF ELSE ENDIF" like sentence whichs allows it to conditionally generate parts of a document. 
It's also capable of using variables provided by the programmer, besides the datatables. I'm panning to include many other features such as formatting functions, raising events, etc.
It will be a commercial product (a really very cheap one), and even it's still under development and needs much more testing, I'm pretty happy with it so far. If you are interested in hearing about it, keep in touch.
Regards,

Gonzalo

Comment: Throw up a link and I'll give it a try.  Oh and use something like IronRuby instead of a custom programming language.

Comment: Hello runxc1 Bret Ferrier,

It's not uploaded anyware yet. If you provide me your email box I'll send you a beta as soon as I can. 
I don't know what's IronRuby. I'll check it, thanks. Anyway, in my case there are only two control flow sentences: IF and SCAN. You write their conditional expressions as if it was C#.
Email me at desarrollo(dot)uruguay(at)gmail(dot)com.
Regards,

Gonzalo

Comment: I use gmail and my email is just runxc1.

Answer (score 0):

Just was checking my answers and found this one. It's a bit late perhaps but I wouldn't miss the chance to tell you I finally uploaded NTemplates to codeplex.

Check ntemplates.codeplex.com.

Best regards,

Gonzalo