# Text Based Reports (.TXT) Using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I have a need to create text based reports (in .txt format) that includes headers, footers, page numbers, etc.   This would be similar to how one would write reports using COBOL.

Does anyone know of any libraries or third party tools that allows this for .NET applications?

I'm not looking to use Reporting Services or anything.   I simply want to create a dataset and then create my own reports that are nicely formatted and spaced correctly between columns.

Today, I'm kind of accomplishing this (without the headings, page numbering, footers) by encorporating Powershell's format-table command within my application.   It seems to work nicely with formatting my reports without me having to worry about spacing, etc., and I can easily sort the columns.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: ¿Do you need the export of data to be done automatically? or is it ok if you need to trigger it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to check out some [.NET based templating engines](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/template-engines). I've used templating engines before (although not in .NET), and I think they could suit your requirements well.

Take a look at some questions here on SO related to them so you get a feel for what people would recommend. For example, look at;

- [Templating Engine to Generate Simple Reports in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346449/templating-engine-to-generate-simple-reports-in-net)
- [.Net Template Engine/Report Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590772/net-template-engine-report-solution)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a third-party library to accomplish what you need. You just need to loop through your `Collection` then append a delimiter to each record. Then write the `string` as a response with the appropriate `header`.

Here's a sample but the concept stays relevant for any type of `Collection` or `List` types.

[Datatable to Text File](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd19b9/how-to-download-datatable-to-text-file-in-C-Sharp/)

Here's a sample DataTable extension method that converts it to string for output with optional delimiter.

```
public static string GetStringSeperatedBy(this DataTable dt, string delimiter)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => string.Format("\"{0}\"", column.ColumnName)).ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       var fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Format("\"{0}\"", field.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Replace("\"", ""))).ToArray();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, fields));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks --I was just trying to avoid a bunch of Console.WriteLines with String.Format(), if I could help it.  I'm trying to write tabular-style reports.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more concrete code implementation.